# How to find the name of a min (or max) attribute?

Tags: python, list

Given three or more variables, I want to find the name of the variable with the min value.

I can get the min value from the list, and I can get the index within the list of the min value. But I want the variable name.

I feel like there's another way to go about this that I'm just not thinking of.

```
a = 12
b = 9
c = 42
cab = [c,a,b]

# yields 9 (the min value)
min(cab) 

# yields 2 (the index of the min value)
cab.index(min(cab))
```

What code would yield 'b'?

Comment: NOTHING would yield 'b'.  `cab` is nothing more than a list containing three integers; there is absolutely no connection to the variables that those integers originally came from.

Comment: I over simplified. a,b, and c are actually stand-ins for attributes of a class. I want to find which attribute has the lowest value. I'm less concerned with the fact that the min value is 9, and more that object.b is less than object.a and object.c . So if these where character stats, I'd want to be able to find which stat was the weakest and increase that stat (whichever it is).

Comment: Doesn't matter; `[foo.c, foo.a, foo.b]` is *also* just a list of values with no memory of where the values came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic of `vars` prevents you from having to make a dictionary up front if you want to have things in instance variables:

```
class Foo():
   def __init__(self, a, b, c):
     self.a = a
     self.b = b
     self.c = c

   def min_name(self, names = None):
     d = vars(self)
     if not names:
       names = d.keys()

     key_min = min(names, key = (lambda k: d[k]))
     return key_min
```

In action

```
>>> x = Foo(1,2,3)
>>> x.min_name()
 'a'
>>> x.min_name(['b','c'])
 'b'
>>> x = Foo(5,1,10)
>>> x.min_name()
 'b'
```

Right now it'll crash if you pass an invalid variable name in the parameter list for `min_name`, but that's resolvable.

You can also update the dictionary and it's reflected in the source

```
  def increment_min(self):
    key = self.min_name()
    vars(self)[key] += 1
```

Example:

```
>>> x = Foo(2,3,4)
>>> x.increment_min()
>>> x.a
3
```

Comment: OH, that's even better. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

<s>You cannot get the name of the variable with the minimum/maximum value like this</s><sup>*</sup>, since as @jasonharper commented: `cab` is nothing more than a list containing three integers; there is absolutely no connection to the variables that those integers originally came from.

A simple workaround is to user *pairs*, like this:

```
>>> pairs = [("a", 12), ("b", 9), ("c", 42)]
>>> min(pairs)
('b', 9)
>>> min(pairs)[0]
'b'
```

<sub>See Green Cloak Guy's answer, but if you want to go for readability, I suggest following a similar approach to mine.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to get very creative for this to work, and the only solution I can think of is rather inefficient.

You can get the memory address of the data `b` refers to fairly easily:

```
>>> hex(id(b))
'0xaadd60'
>>> hex(id(cab[2]))
'0xaadd60'
```

To actually correspond that with a variable name, though, the only way to do that would be to look through the variables and find the one that points to the right place.

You can do this by using the `globals()` function:

```
# get a list of all the variable names in the current namespace that reference your desired value
referent_vars = [k for k,v in globals().items() if id(v) == id(cab[2])]
var_name = referent_vars[0]
```

There are two big problems with this solution:

1. Namespaces - you can't put this code in a function, because if you do that and then call it from another function, then it won't work.
2. Time - this requires searching through the entire global namespace.

The first problem could be alleviated by additionally passing the current namespace in as a variable:

```
def get_referent_vars(val, globals):
    return [k for k,v in globals.items() if id(v) == id(val)]

def main():
    a = 12
    b = 9
    c = 42
    cab = [a, b, c]

    var_name = get_referent_vars(
            cab[cab.index(min(cab))], 
            globals()
        )[0]
    print(var_name)
    # should print 'b'
```

Comment: Feasible then, nice! Tried it in a shell - it works there!

Comment: As a note, this only works if the variables stay what they are. If at any point you assign over them and overwrite the names in the namespace, it ceases to work. It's pretty much the only immutable thing *in* python, but **memory is immutable**, so keep in mind that you can't ever change either `b` or `cab[2]`, or else it'll break.

Comment: Yes that would make sense Green Cloak Guy, I agree.

Comment: This is awesome information, and definitely gets at what I actually asked. I think gsamaras' answer gets more at what I meant to ask. I can use a simple dictionary to get at what attribute holds the min val. Thank you both!!

Comment: There's another much more Pythonic way ... see my answer above.